# SharePoint 2013 - Enumerate all subsites using CSOM and authentication code flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, sub-site

I'm trying to enumerate all sites that a user has access to underneath a given site in sharepoint. For example, given I've authenticated to `https://offtechsmith.sharepoint.com/teams/teamsite`, I want to enumerate the two subsites `https://offtechsmith.sharepoint.com/teams/teamsite/dev-testing` and `https://offtechsmith.sharepoint.com/teams/teamsite/dev-testing-2`.

I'm authenticating using the scope `Web.Read` when logging in via OAuth.

The code I'm using is

```
using ( ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken( sharepointUrl.AbsoluteUri, accessToken ) )
{
    WebCollection webCollectionResult = clientContext.Web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser( new SubwebQuery() );
    IEnumerable<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web> result = clientContext.LoadQuery( webCollectionResult ); 
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

When I do that I get back the following error: `Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.`. Is there a different scope I should be requesting to make this call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need read permissions on the site collection to view other sites in it.  You can read up more on the app permission model [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383(v=office.15).aspx).

Alternatively, you can use REST, and use the search endpoint, which will automatically trim the results for you.

Comment: I'm doing on the fly permission request so I don't think I can ask for the `Site.Read` scope since most users (non-admins) won't be able to grant it. What would a search query look like for subsites?

Comment: I believe you can use CSOM for search as well.  The query text would look like this: `contentclass:STS_Web Path:https://offtechsmith.sharepoint.com/teams/teamsite`.  It retrieves all Webs from the Site that the user has access to.